# Cannot find MacOS.so

Tags: python, macos

Hi I'm trying to use a Python library which apparently must load code from `MacOS.so`, but it cannot be found on my system. I've tried linking to other ones found with the `locate` command, but with complaints about `flat namespace`.

I'm wondering if it's required then why is it not packaged with other libraries? Where can I find the source for it perhaps, or even just more information about it?

Cheers

Comment: What Python library?  What Python?  What version of OS X? Please show the exact error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Mac OS you'll have a different version of Python installed by default.  Assuming you're running Snow Leopard (10.6.x), that version is Python 2.6.1.

`MacOS.so` can be found here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/MacOS.so`

You shouldn't really have to worry about this.  If you're using the default installation of Python found at `/usr/bin/python`, utilizing this module is as simple as:

```
import MacOS
```